# Is there an implementation of POSIX semaphore not based on Mutex+CV?

Tags: multithreading, real-time

I read that semaphores in the FreeBSD kernel is not as efficient as Mutex+CV from [this man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sema&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports). I've examined the kernel and syscall implementation of POSIX semaphore from the [source](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/sys/kern/uipc_sem.c) [code](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/sys/kern/kern_sema.c) and confirmed that they're implemented on top of Mutex+CV.

It might have been **a misconception of mine** that, POSIX semaphores, as a real-time synchornization primitive, should be very efficient. But after reading and seeing those, I'm not sure how efficient they're supposed to be.

Also, I'm reading the book [Concurrent Programming: Algorithms, Principles, and Foundations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-32027-9). Right now, I haven't finished reading the first part, but it's about to introduce monitors (CV) implemented on top of semaphores. This got me thinking, there must be an efficient real-world implementation of semaphore not based on Mutex+CV that's more efficient.

Is there a *real-world* implementation of semaphore not based on Mutex+CV?

Answer (score 0):

The [Linux implementation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/locking/semaphore.c?h=v5.19) doesn't seem to use CV, but it uses a kernel-space lock to protect the semaphore state.